# Writing an Image with unique id

Tags: matlab

First, select an input image clicking on "Select image".

```
% Then you can
%   - add this image to database (click on "Add selected image to database"
% 
%  If you choose to add image to database, a positive integer (sign ID) is
%  required. This posivive integer is a progressive number which identifies
%  a person (each person corresponds to a class).
% For example:
%
%  - add "mike1.jpg" to database ---> the ID has to be 1 since Mike is the first
%    person you are adding to database
%  - add "mike2.jpg" to database ---> the ID has to be 1 since you have already
%    added a Mike's image to database
%  - add "paul1.jpg" to database ---> the ID has to be 2 since Paul is the second person
%    you are adding to database
%  - add "cindy1.jpg" to database ---> the ID has to be 3 since Cindy is
%    the third person you are adding to database
%  - add "paul2.jpg" to database ---> the ID has to be 2 once again since
%    you have already added Paul to database
```

How to assign this unique sign id??

Comment: Please paste the code where you are saving the image

Comment: Sir, my code is the same as the one I posted before, My doubt is how do I save image once the image is normalized in my current working directory with unique id?

Answer (score 0):

As you are loading a image and have processing on it, you can save it with the exact name you have load. Also you can add prefix and postfix to it.

Some times, based on what you want, you can append time and date at the end of image name.

In your case you have `filename` in

```
[filename, pathname, filterindex] = uigetfile('*.jpg', 'Pick a .jpg image');
```

Just do something like:

```
[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(filename) 
newFileName = name + '_normalize' + ext;
```

Instead of `'_normalize'` you can add any postfix you want

If you want to add date and time, you can use `datetime('now')`